# R: define value as range / interval

Tags: r, range, intervals, bounds

I've looked around but could not find an answer that helps. I'm trying to set up a key-value table in R where the key is defined as range or interval so that I can do a look-up to find the value of any key that falls within the range / interval.
To give a minimal example which does not work.

```
data.frame(key = c(range(0, 1),
                   range(1, 2)),
           value = c("A", 
                     "B"))
```

The data frame would not hold two rows but four since R is treating lower and upper interval bound as two separate values and recycle the value column to arrive at four rows. Besides this problem, I could also not find a range / interval function where I can define lower and upper bounds.

EDIT:
The desired output would be a table like this:

```
key      value    
(0, 1)   "A"
(1, 2)   "B"
```

So I could do something like the following query for a value a:
table$value[where a %in% table$key]

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Isn't it something that the function `findInterval` could do?

Comment: Yes findInterval can tell me if a value is in my range but how do I define a column in a data frame to hold values that are ranges?

Comment: How are you going to use these values? This looks nice but quite useless unless you will use regex in order to extract them. Isn't it better to just create two columns instead?

Comment: IMO you should create two columns one for the lower bound and another for the upper bound of the range...

Comment: Ok. I was afraid that this is the answer. The problem is that I can only have one key in the key-value table and this key should be a range. Having two columns requires defining secondary key. I'm basically trying to mimic a data warehouse star schema with different tables. The idea was to reference from a fact table to a dimension table where the key of the dimension table is a range. But that might not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really elegant but you can do this to make it practical and handy:

```
df = data.frame(values=letters[1:2])
df$keys=list(0:1, 1:2)
#  values keys
#1      a 0, 1
#2      b 1, 2
```

So that you do not need `regex` like when accessing the data with `df$keys`.

Comment: That might help. I'm now struggling how to efficiently get back the values from values column for an input e.g. a <- 0.5. I tried this df$values[findInterval(a, df$keys)]. But that gives an error. I guess I have to use a different approach for lists?

Comment: you can do `df$values[sapply(df$keys, function(u) head(u,1)<0.5 & 0.5<=tail(u,1))]` even if I thnik an approach with the columns, first and second part of the key, is better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, you want to find the interval where each value occurs. If that is the case, then you can do so by finding the minimum and maximum "key" numbers for each of the "value" numbers.

This can be easily achieved using the `dplyr` package as follows:

```
#If not installed do install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

#Provided example
df = data.frame(key = c(range(0, 1),range(1, 2)),
                value = c("A", "B"))

#First group data by "value" variable
# and then paste a vector with min and max of "key" variable
df2 = df %>% 
      group_by(value) %>% 
      summarise(key = paste0("(", min(key), ",", max(key), ")"))
```

Result:

```
  value   key
1     A (0,1)
2     B (1,2)
```

You can easily get the values in an interval by doing:

```
subset(df2, key == "(0,1)")$value
```

This solution is general (it doesn't matter how many values you have). Also, if that is of interest, you could just as easily return minimum and maximum columns, instead of the format `(min,max)`

```
df3 = df %>% 
      group_by(value) %>% 
      summarise(min = min(key), 
                max = max(key))
```

Results in:

```
  value min max
1     A   0   1
2     B   1   2
```

And you can get the desired interval by doing:

```
subset(df3, min >= 0 & max <= 1)$value
```

Comment: thanks a ton for the example! will have to look into it in detail on monday as time is running out. will let you know if that is better than @Colonel Beauvel solution.